# POST routes in LARAVEL 6

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, routes

I'm developping an application in laravel 6 and i have some issues.
I have an API for communicate with my BDD and I make  GET routes for displaying some data.
I'm now trying to make POST routes for UPDATE my BDD with data collecting on form with my application but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Hi, you will find your answer in the Laravel documentation. We can only help you with defined errors or issues. Please study the documentation and make a new post if you run into an actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you're creating a very common blog app

the basic endpoints for our application: create, retrieve the list, retrieve a single one, update, and delete. On the routes/api.php file, we can simply do this:

```
Use App\Article;

Route::get('articles', function() {
    // If the Content-Type and Accept headers are set to 'application/json', 
    // this will return a JSON structure. This will be cleaned up later.
    return Article::all();
});

Route::get('articles/{id}', function($id) {
    return Article::find($id);
});

Route::post('articles', function(Request $request) {
    return Article::create($request->all);
});

Route::put('articles/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $article->update($request->all());

    return $article;
});

Route::delete('articles/{id}', function($id) {
    Article::find($id)->delete();

    return 204;
});
```

Now let’s move this code to its own Controller:

```
php artisan make:controller ArticleController
```

The `ArticleController.php` file:

```
use App\Article;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Article::all();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return Article::find($id);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return Article::create($request->all());
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $article->update($request->all());

        return $article;
    }

    public function delete(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $article->delete();

        return 204;
    }
}
```

The `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');
Route::put('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');
Route::delete('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete');
```

[From/Source](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial)